# Decrypting using CCCrypt returns different results on iOS and MacOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, encryption

Decrypting using CCCrypt returns different results on iOS (5,6) and MacOS 10.7.
Same code running in different platforms/architectures produces different outputs with the same input. Why? and how to fix it?

I have debugged everything. All the variables share the same value either running on the Mac or in the iPhone. The point where they bifurcate is:

```
ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, //decrypt 
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128, //AES128
                       0, // mode - no Padding
                       rawAESKey, // simmetric key
                       kCCKeySizeAES128, //key size
                       iv, 
                       dataIn, dataInBytesSize, //input 
                       dataOut, dataOutBytesSize, //output
                       &clearTextSize);
```

At this point, `dataOut` has different values depending if it's running in the mac, and in the iPhone. `ccStatus` returns success in both cases.

Note:
Xcode Version 4.6.2 (4H1003)
iOS SDK 5,6 - binary produced as 32 bits
MacOS SDK 10.7 - binary produced as 64 bits